# Is iOS 11 Beta IPSW package already in APFS? How to open/extract it on Windows?

Tags: windows, mac, 7-zip, ios, hfs+

I want to extract the iOS 11 Beta IPSW to extract it's ringtones and maybe even wallpapers. But I don't have a Mac to open it.

I already opened the IPSW, but the DMGs inside it is my problem. I've known before that Apple already upgraded iOS devices to APFS since iOS 10.3 and as optional since Sierra.

I have 7zip on my PC that said to support DMG files, but this DMG files looks like they're already formatted to APFS since it's already passed iOS 10.3 that's why I'm not able to read it.

Paragon HFS+ tool also still not able to support this, and still not planning to do so in the future since as I've known this is still in Beta and still not open source, am I right?

How can I extract this file using Windows?

Answer (score -1):

If 7Zip does not do the job, try these tools :

- Append `.iso` to the file and try to open it as ISO.
- Use [**dmg2img**](http://vu1tur.eu.org/tools/) (free).
- The Catacombae products [**HFSExplorer**](http://catacombae.org/hfsexplorer/) and [**DMGExtractor**](http://catacombae.org/typhertransfer/)
  (Requires Java SE Runtime Environment version 5.0 or greater).
  [image]
- [**TransMac**](http://www.acutesystems.com/scrtm.htm) (shareware $59)
  [image]

Comment: Thanks for this, now that I've opened that IPSW now, I want to ask if you're familiar where is the directory on media files, like ringtones or wallpapers on this firmware software update package?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not on the Mac.